# asyncio: RuntimeError: no running event loop while running widgets

Tags: python, widget, python-asyncio, ipython, ipywidgets

I try to show widget with two buttons (in file wait_action.py):

```
    from ipywidgets import Button, HBox
    from IPython.display import clear_output
    import asyncio
    
    def wait_for_change(widget1, widget2):
        future = asyncio.Future()
        def getvalue(change):
            future.set_result(change.description)
            widget1.on_click(getvalue, remove=True)
            widget2.on_click(getvalue, remove=True)
        widget1.on_click(getvalue)
        widget2.on_click(getvalue)
        return future
    
    def show_button():
        button1 = Button(description='Track & Push', button_style='success')
        button2 = Button(description='Continue', button_style='info')
        async def interaction():
            x = await wait_for_change(button1, button2)
            if x == "Track & Push":
                print('saving')
            else:
                print("continue")
            clear_output()
        print('Save results of current pipeline step?')
        asyncio.create_task(interaction())
        return HBox([button1, button2])
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        show_button()

venv/bin/python3.10 src/utils/wait_action.py
```

But I run into the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "src/utils/wait_action.py", line 31, in show_button
    asyncio.create_task(interaction(button1, button2))
  File "/usr/local/basement/Python-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 336, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'interaction' was never awaited
```

But if you run the function `show_button` in a separate cell of notebook, there will be no error. Why?

Thank you in advance